# Generating JSON POJOS from a REST call

Tags: java, android, json

I have integrated spring rest templates in my android project.

For this I have to map all of my JSON requests and response's into `java` pojos.

Is there any tool that can generate these classes for me ?

I mean take a json string and give me a java class file with the all the getters, setters and attributes ? I dont mean map a json object to my java object, i mean more like in WSDL where given a service the compiler creates the class files automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link you can try this to generate java classe online. 
[link to generate java class as save as zip](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/)

For offline you can can take a help of [astav offline generator](https://github.com/astav/JsonToJava)

Download the library there is a sample generator. Edit `.sh` file and change `json` file name as per to your `json` file name.

Or simply replace content of `sample.json` file with your actual content and run `.sh` file.

Comment: This is exactly what i need, but the json string has to be some place. Is there no library that we can download to do this ?

Comment: hmm little tough let me search some tool or code to help you.

Comment: @Real, the link was too good but api is not freely available.

Comment: @subodh added offline generator open source API

Comment: @Real,+1 for that link too